# Alternatives to Bayer process for extracting aluminum from lunar regolith

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrolysis, electronegativity

I am exploring ways to produce metallic aluminum from lunar regolith. According to most published results of lunar soil, $\ce{ Al2O3}$ comprises roughly 14% of mare samples by mass with $\ce{SiO2}$ being main impurity (40%). From what I been able to understand so far, both Bayer and Serpeck’s processes rely on reagents that can't be produced in-situ. Hence, the challenge is to use the least amount of chemistry to refine lunar material to the point when electrolysis can be used. Maybe magnetic separation?  [Is Al2O3 (aluminum oxide) diamagnetic or paramagnetic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/106931/is-al2o3-aluminum-oxide-diamagnetic-or-paramagnetic?newreg=5dfdafe24e6b4b2b84e9f37ae77998c6)

Comment: I maybe have missed something so let tell me what you are asking.

Comment: If the Moon's crust is anything like Earth's, most of the 14% Al2O3 is not a physical mixture with the 40% silica, plus whatever else is in the regolith.  Most of the alumina is chemically combined with silica, so we will need to be able to extract the alumina or some other aluminum compound chemically.  Sounds like fun :-( .